# Error in " SaveChanges() " method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating an application using an Oracle database and ASP.net MVC4. Even though it seems like no problems in the code, calling the `SaveChanges()` method causes an error shown here:

[image]

This image shows the inner exception and related details

[image]

This is the implementation that I have done for saving changes

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ModelState.Clear();

    using (SSP_Entities database = new SSP_Entities())
    {
          database.REQUEST_TAB.Add(c_modal.Request_tab);
          database.SaveChanges();
          caseID = c_modal.Request_tab.CASE_ID;
          return RedirectToAction("NewEnv", cpe);
     }
  }
```

I use following code in the view

```
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.request_tab.ROWVERSION, new { @Value="date"}) %>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.request_tab.CASE_ID, new { @Value=100}) %>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.request_tab.REQUEST_BY, new { @Value="PUSNLK"}) %>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.request_tab.REQUEST_ID, new { @Value=334}) %>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.request_tab.REQUEST_TYPE, new { @Value="CPE"}) %>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.request_tab.STATE, new { @Value="POSTED"}) %>
    <%:Html.HiddenFor(model => model.request_tab.COMMENTS, new { @Value="CPE Order"}) %>
```

This is the model that I'm using

```
namespace CPEASPX.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class REQUEST_TAB
    {
        public decimal REQUEST_ID { get; set; }
        public string REQUEST_BY { get; set; }
        public decimal CASE_ID { get; set; }
        public string STATE { get; set; }
        public string REQUEST_TYPE { get; set; }
        public string ROWVERSION { get; set; }
        public string COMMENTS { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried a few solutions shown elsewhere. First I changed the `<appSettings>` in `web.config` file by adding

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5000" />
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="5000" />
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="10000" />
```

lines to it. But the problem continues. I cannot find any mismatch between client and server data types.

Please help me to sort out the problem.

Here im passing two models to a single view. i created following combined model for that(c_model is an object of this class)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CPEASPX.Models
{
    public class CombineModal
    {
        public REQUEST_TAB request_tab = new REQUEST_TAB();

        public REQUEST_TAB Request_tab
        {
        get { return request_tab; }
        set { request_tab = value; }
        }


        public CPE cpe = new CPE();

        public CPE Cpe
        {
            get { return cpe; }
            set { cpe = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

here it says i'm passing CPE model to it but i'm only passing combined model which contains CPE modal and Request_tab modal in it.

this is the code that i use in the view to inherit the modal class

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<CPEASPX.Models.CombineModal>" %>
```

Comment: What does the declaration of the viewmodel look like?

Comment: didn't get you.. you meen the modal class ?

Comment: Can you output the base exception - `exception.GetBaseException()` so we can see what the first error is?

Comment: @Sandaru Yes, I meant the class for c_model.

Comment: this is the Base exception that i'm getting "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'CPEASPX.Models.CPE', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CPEASPX.Models.CombineModal'."

Comment: actually i pass two models to a single view therefore im using a combined modal i will update the code with that

Comment: Hmm.. I don't understand the need to request_tab backing field, but if you use a backing field it should be private. In your view you bind to request_tab instead of Request_tab. I would've changed that.

Comment: The exception you get doesn't seem possible to achieve in the code you have pasted here. Basically the exception says that you try to put the Cpe property into a dictionary that expects a CombineModal property. I can't see any code that does this. Have you checked where the exception occurs?

Comment: i found the solution... it was not about client side but about server side. This occurs when database refuse the operation. as i got,  actual meaning of the error message is "object doesn't have permission to do this operation". So i double checked the database permissions and data types by validating. finally i found that i have 4 keys in my database which i didn't declare by my self. so i recreated the database and problem disappeared... Thanks for your kind help :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to assign each property instead of add whole class.

```
using (SSP_Entities database = new SSP_Entities())
{
    var requestTab = new RequestTab
    {
        REQUEST_ID = c_modal.Request_tab.REQUEST_ID,
        REQUEST_BY = c_modal.Request_tab.REQUEST_BY,
        CASE_ID = c_modal.Request_tab.CASE_ID,
        STATE = c_modal.Request_tab.STATE,
        REQUEST_TYPE = c_modal.Request_tab.REQUEST_TYPE,
        ROWVERSION = c_modal.Request_tab.ROWVERSION,
        COMMENTS = c_modal.Request_tab.COMMENTS
    };

    database.REQUEST_TAB.Add(requestTab);
    database.SaveChanges();
}
```